# ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync() fails from desktop app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

I am creating a WPF desktop app that accesses the Windows 10 Runtime APIs.

If I use the **ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync()** API it fails with an **InvalidOperationException**

```
HResult=-2147009196
Message=The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)
```

Is it possible to use this API from a WPF desktop App?  Can I add a package identity to it?  How else can I create a StorageFile in a Windows desktop app?

Answer (score 2):

A desktop application does not have a package identity. You can use [Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) (DAC) to generate a package for your desktop app. After packaging the WPF exe as an appx using `DAC`, and installing the appx, the app works as expected.

`DAC` requires the Pro or Enterprise edition, though.

But you can use `StorageFolder/StorageFile` directly from desktop app without having to convert the app to package before hand. The error you encountered was because `ApplicationData.Current` maps to a folder which does not exist for a desktop app.

This piece of code creates and writes to a file in temporary folder using WinRT APIs.

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("helloworld.txt");            
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "hahahaha");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StorageFile` type is only supported for Windows Store apps. It is used because the apps are sandboxed and memory optimized. In WPF you have full access to the hard disk, so could just write data out to any file, any place you want, or just store it in process memory if it's not too big.

I think the equivalent in WPF would be to use `Path.GetTempFileName` to get a path to a temporary file and then use some file writer class to write to disk.